# String replace PHP

Tags: php

```
Array {
    [0] => http://abc.com/video/ghgh23;
    [1] => http://smtech.com/file/mwerq2;
}
```

I want to replace the content between `/`sometext`/` from the above array. Like I want to replace `video`, `file` with `abc`.

Comment: Have a look at `preg_replace` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop over every element of the array, [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) can take an array to replace with:

```
$myArray = str_replace(array('/video/', '/file/'), '/abc/', $myArray);
```

However, based on your question, you might want to replace the first path segment, and not a specific index.  So to do that:

```
$myArray = preg_replace('((?<!/)/([^/]+)/)', '/abc/', $myArray);
```

That will replace the first path element of every URL in `$myArray` with `/abc/`...

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use str_replace()
You can check it out here: http://php.net/str_replace

Answer (score 0):

Either `str_replace` as other comments suggested or using a regular expression especially if you might have a longer url with more segments like `http://example.com/xxx/somestuff/morestuff` 
In that case str_replace will not be enough you will need `preg_replace`

Answer (score 0):

```
//every element in $myArray

for($i=0; $i < count($myArray); $i++){

    $myArray[$i] = str_replace('/video/','/abc/',$myArray[$i]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another option.  Supply a array, foreach will pick it up and then the first parameter of str_replace can be a array if needed.  Hope you find this helpful.

```
<?php

$array = array('http://abc.com/video/ghgh23','http://smtech.com/file/mwerq2');
$newarray = array();

foreach($array as $url) {
 $newarray[] = str_replace(array('video','file'),'abc',$url);
}

print_r($newarray);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('http://abc.com/video/ghgh23', 'http://smtech.com/file/mwerq2');
foreach ($array as &$string)
{
    $string = str_replace('video', 'abc', $string);
    $string = str_replace('file', 'abc', $string);
}
```